# VS Code on macOS with cpptools 1.71.1+: When trying to compile code in C++, "-std=gnu++14" appears before all the flags. How to delete it?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am a beginner, using VSCode on macOS.
Trying to iterate using square brackets which is requires C++17:

```
for (auto [document_id, relevance] : documents) {
            cout << "{ document_id = "s << document_id << ", relevance = "s << relevance << " }"s
                 << endl;
        }
```

When trying to Terminal -> Run build task, *-std=gnu++14* flag appears before all other flags, even if *-std=gnu++17* specified in tasks.json

Here are my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=gnu++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "/usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang++ 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++14 -std=gnu++17 -stdlib=libc++ -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/user/Documents/С++/000test/main.cpp -o /Users/user/Documents/С++/000test/main

Build finished successfully.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

What could be the problem?

I also tried to change the C++ version to 17 in the C/C++ extension, but to no avail.

When running with `"-std=gnu++17", "-stdlib=libc++"` in tasks json no warning appears, but does the second -std flag override the first one?

I also found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73327993/why-is-cmake-putting-std-gnu14-in-clang-invocations-when-i-dont-specify-gcc), but I dont even have CMake extension in vscode.

Comment: Apologies for asking the obvious, but you did save the files after editing right? It seems fairly common for folks using VSCode to forget that.

Comment: Are you maybe using code runner?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, both files saved,  even tried to close and run vscode before running a program again

Comment: @AlanBirtles Its C/C++ extension package from which I deleted CMake just in case, since I don't need it right now. No code runner installed. Code is running fine with -std=gnu++17 in tasks.json

Comment: @273K Thank you for correcting me and I apologize if I did not describe something clearly. Added output. I'm running "C/C++: clang++" task

Comment: `/usr/bin/clang++` in the terminal looks like an alias for `/usr/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++14`.

Comment: what is "Terminal -> Run Build Task"? How exactly do you invoke that action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is hard coded into the c++ extension:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/dec50598bc4d169b38292d2f4ff26a216d3c6342/Extension/src/LanguageServer/cppBuildTaskProvider.ts#L370

`insertStd` is set to true for clang on macos.

I'd raise a bug with Microsoft but in the meantime just don't build directly with tasks, use cmake or another build system and you'll avoid this problem.

This was added recently: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/pull/11300

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563269/passing-multiple-std-switches-to-g

Comment: Hold up, what's the trigger here? `"command"` == clang++? That PR thread looks like it should only trigger when you're building a file without `tasks.json`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i think it's for the default generated task that you get when you to to build the active file, not sure how it works, I've only ever used cmake

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you! I downgraded the C/C++ extension and that solved the problem.